# How do I render .NET WebBrowser's modified DOM to HTML?

Tags: .net, dom, browser, web

I have a .NET web browser and through DOM I am making certain changes in the page's elements

such as:

Title and changing inner text of some of elements by ID.

Now all this works fine and I can call the document's individual elements to make sure changes were made.

Webrowser.Body.Getelementbyid("id") <--- I can see changes

Webbrowser.Document.Title <---- I can see changes

But if I go to top level and view the HTML like

Webbrowser.DocumentText  <--- I do not see any changes

Purpose is to save all the HTML after making necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't. You're trying to force the web browser control to be a designer and that won't happen.

This is because the browser does not apply your DOM changes to the HTML and reinterprets. All your changes are in-memory. Seeing those changes reflected in the HTML constitutes a feature provided by HTML designers, and the .NET web browser is just a browser, not a designer.

Comment: If the HTML is well-formed and conforms to standards you might be able to treat it as a sort of XML doc and do the updates to the source yourself. Or you could check for 3rd party solutions that might provide the kind of functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Paul, I am now able to to get the changes using WebBrowser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml  . I went a level down to body and went back to parent node which is actualy root. But it solved only one problem which is getting the changes. It raised another issue which is it gets the rendered HTML not original HTML. I need a work around this.

Comment: I'm surprised that it provides rendered HTML but it makes sense I suppose. But, per my answer, you will not be able to get the original HTML with your updates without a VERY significant amount of work.